# Uniqueness in Mantel Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In Mantel's Theorem: I know that $K_{\lceil n/2 \rceil , \lfloor n/2 \rfloor} $ achieves the maximum number of edges without having a triangle. But why is it the unique example?

Comment: You should provide a source for your statement of Mantel's Theorem and for the $K_{\lceil n/2 \rceil, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ claim. After googling around (briefly) I can't find anything regarding  $K_{\lceil n/2 \rceil, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$.

Answer (score 1):

From the proof of Mantel's theorem see [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/EGT1.pdf),one step is
$$\left(\sum_{x\in G}d^2(x)\right)\left(\sum_{x\in G}1^2\right)\ge\left(\sum_{x\in G}d(x)\right)^2$$
This achieves equality iff $d(x)$ are all equal, which means the graph is regular. On the other hand, since we have $n^2/4$ edges, the valency of each point is $n/2$. Thus if we choose a $x$ and consider all points connected to it, denoted by $N(x)$. If $y,z\not\in N(x)$, $y,z\not= x$, $y$ should not be connected to $z$. This is because if $y$ is connected to $z$, then $N(y)\cap N(z)\not = \varnothing$ since $(n/2-1)+(n/2-1)>n-3$, which is the number of points excluding $x,y$ and $z$. Thus $y$ should only be connected to $N(x)$, which means the graph is $K_{[n/2],[n/2]}$